# resolution independent grid for animations?

Tags: c#, xna, grid, positioning, pixel

I'm working on a game made in XNA,C# and I want to enable xml based animations.

XML will look like this

```xml
<Animation>
<AnimatedObject>
<Filename>Spaceship_Jet_01</Filename>
<Flipped>false</Flipped>
<StartPosition_X>300</StartPosition_X>
<StartPosition_Y>500</StartPosition_Y>
<GOTOPosition_X>650</GOTOPosition_X>
<GOTOPosition_Y>500</GOTOPosition_Y>
<Time>10000</Time>
</AnimatedObject>
</Animation>
```

This will move an object to the side, like this
http://imm.io/odc7 (sorry the X coordinate is wrong)

I noticed there will be problems, when the players display resolution is different from mine because I enter pixel precise information about where the object comes from and where it has to go.

I thought about a grid so I can tell the programm to move the object from (30,27) to  (22,27) e.g.. Is this a good solution? The grid has to be independent from the resolution but the number of tiles has to be constant and I have to draw the object to the screen. That means I have to find the right pixle position of the tile at position (22,27) and then "move" the object to that tile.

Is there a better way to do that? How can I solve this with XNA?

Comment: How about instead of setting x and y in pixels, set them in percentage where, for example, 0 value for x would mean far left and 1 would mean far right? Then you can easily calculate the target position, you just do XValue * GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth; or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a 2D camera you won't have any problem... because calculating the new view to adapt it to the new resolution is not difficult.... and you have not to change anything of your loads methods nor logic...

You can do, but I don`t like

1. Work with positions in [0..1] range, is difficult to measure.
2. Fix the position with the new resolution factor when you load the xml... is ugly...

   ```
   Pos *= NewResolutionSize/DefaultResolutionSize;
   ```

Comment: Thank you this Pos *= NewResolutionSize/DefaultResolutionSize;
solved my problem